# Объединить массивы в зависимости от размера максимального массива

Tags: php

Есть необходимость объединять элементы массива в дополнительные массивы внутри, если их итоговая длина после объединения равна максимальной длине элемента этого же массива. Пример:

```
Array
(
    [house_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                )

        )

    [house_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                )

        )

    [house_3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 99
                )

        )

)
```

Я пытаюсь, но не могу добиться автоматического объединения массивов house_2 и house_3 в один массив внутри этого же массива, поскольку их длина по отдельности меньше длины наибольшего массива (house_1).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите код ваших попыток, и мы подскажем в чем может быть дело